# Access prestashop back office values

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

[Backoffice Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl7nW.png)
This is the image of product characteristics from prestashop backoffice. Can anyone please tell me how to access these characteristics in controller?From last 2-3 days I am working on this only

Answer (score 0):

Those are `Feature`s, see for classes `Feature`, `FeatureValue`, and in database:

`PREFIX_feature`
`PREFIX_feature_value`

and `_lang` tables related to those.

Those classes have all methods needed for working with values.